# Find most common substring from an Array of Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search, longest-substring

I want to search a word from an array of strings.

```
array = ["ram","gopal","varma","govind","ravan","alan"]
```

if my search text is `goal` i want to list as follows:

```
result = ["gopal","govind","alan"]
```

ie in `gopal` & `goal` only `p` is missing so it should be in search list with higher priority.

Is there any way to do such filtering?

Comment: you need single object or multiple object ?

Comment: Actually i want an array of items as shown in question. ie all items from that contains the subsequences of search text. but most similar word should show as first in list.

Comment: There is an `a` in `"ram"` and others. Should the common subsequence at least have 2 characters?

Comment: array = ["ram","gopal","varma","govind","varma","ravan","gopal","ravan","alan"] what will be the output? of this array please share.

Comment: @Carpsen90  yes thats true. Am used above result just to show my priority.
 varma, ram, ravan also should be in list because of a in common.
result = ["gopal","govind","alan"," varma", "ravan", "ram"]

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longest common subsequence between two strings can be defined recursively as follows :

```
func lcs(_ str1: String, _ str2: String, _ i: String.Index, _ j: String.Index) -> Int 
{
    if (i == str1.startIndex || j == str2.startIndex) {
        return 0
    }

    let beforeI = str1.index(before: i)
    let beforeJ = str2.index(before: j)

    if str1[beforeI] == str2[beforeJ] {
        return 1 + lcs(str1, str2, beforeI, beforeJ)
    } else {
        return max(lcs(str1, str2, i, beforeJ), lcs(str1, str2, beforeI, j))
    }
}
```

You can find a complete explanation of how this dynamic programming algorithm works [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoaQq66foQ).

So, given an array of strings and a search text :

```
let array = ["ram", "gopal", "varma", "govind", "ravan", "alan", "logan"]
let searchText = "goal"
```

We can associate a score to each element of the array, filter only those that have a non-zero score, sort them by score, and then only key the words from the tuples :

```
let result = array
    .map { ($0, lcs(searchText,
                    $0,
                    searchText.endIndex,
                    $0.endIndex)) }
    .filter { $0.1 > 0 }
    .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    .map { $0.0 }

print(result)
```

Which yields :

> `["gopal", "govind", "alan", "logan", "ram", "varma", "ravan"]`

Answer (score 0):

You want to find longest common subsequences. I would suggest you to look at [this](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Longest%20Common%20Subsequence) excelent article on Ray Wenderlich's Swift Algorithm Club where you can find your solution with examples.

EDIT:

Then you have to iterate over your array and keep track of how long a subsequence is for each world (for example in dictionary). Then you have to sort your array by the subsequences lengths.

For example like this:

```
let array = ["ram", "gopal", "varma", "govind", "ravan", "alan"]
let searchTerm = "goal"

var dictionary: [String: Int] = [:]
for element in array {
    dictionary[element] = searchTerm.longestCommonSubsequence(element).count
}

let result = dictionary.sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 }).map { $0.key }
```

Comment: yes. i can Longest common subsequence algorithms to find. but that is used for comparing 2 strings right? i have an array of 1000 of items, for that its difficult to do that.

Comment: You have to iterate over your array and keep track of how long a subsequence is for each world (for example in dictionary). Then you have to sort your array by the subsequences lengths.